# I need to show array of an array

Tags: php, laravel, yaml

I'm developing a CMS, which uses yaml files to manipulate the theme. My problem is that I need to list the Submenus of a Menu. I access for example the Header menu where I can change the contents of it, but in that Header has submenus, I just want to list them.

I have a service that does a search

Since the data is an array, how do I print it on the screen?

```
public function query() {

    /* @var $request Request */
    $request = app('request');

    /* @var $website Site */
    $website = $request->route('website');
    $menu = $request->route('submenu');

    // Carega configurações do site
    $this->service->loadWebsite($website->slug);
    /*
    - title: menu1
      submenu:
       - title: submenu 1.1
       - title: submenu 1.2
    - title: menu2
      submenu:
       - title: submenu 2.1
    */


    /*
    - title: menu1
    - title: - submenu 1.1
    - title: - submenu 1.2
    - title: menu2
    - title: - submenu 2.1
    */
    // puxa os menus da configuração do site
    $menus = $this->service->getWebsiteConfig($website->slug, 'menu.' . $menu . '.menu');

    dd($menus);
    return $menus;
}
```

SERVICE

```
 protected function toWebisteMenuItemCollection(string $menu, array $rows) {
    return collect($rows)->map(function (array $data, string $key) use ($menu) {
        $data['id'] = $menu . '.' . $key;
        if(isset($data['submenu']) && is_array($data['submenu'])) {
            $data['submenu'] = $this->toWebisteMenuItemCollection($data['id'], $data['submenu']);
        }

        return new WebsiteMenuItem($data);
    });
}
```

dd($menu)

```
#attributes: array:3 [
    "title" => "Consórcio"
    "submenu" => Collection {#647
      #items: array:3 [
        0 => WebsiteMenuItem {#642
          #keyType: "string"
          #fillable: array:7 [
            0 => "id"
            1 => "title"
            2 => "label"
            3 => "imagem"
            4 => "website_image"
            5 => "icons"
            6 => "submenu"
          ]
          #connection: null
          #table: null
          #primaryKey: "id"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: false
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #attributes: array:2 [
            "title" => "Planos de Consórcio"
            "id" => "header_submenu_menu.2.0"
          ]
          #original: []
          #changes: []
          #casts: []
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #appends: []
          #dispatchesEvents: []
          #observables: []
          #relations: []
          #touches: []
          +timestamps: true
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #guarded: array:1 [
            0 => "*"
          ]
        }
        1 => WebsiteMenuItem {#645
          #keyType: "string"
          #fillable: array:7 [
            0 => "id"
            1 => "title"
            2 => "label"
            3 => "imagem"
            4 => "website_image"
            5 => "icons"
            6 => "submenu"
          ]
          #connection: null
          #table: null
          #primaryKey: "id"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: false
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #attributes: array:2 [
            "title" => "Portal do Consorciado"
            "id" => "header_submenu_menu.2.1"
          ]
          #original: []
          #changes: []
          #casts: []
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #appends: []
          #dispatchesEvents: []
          #observables: []
          #relations: []
          #touches: []
          +timestamps: true
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #guarded: array:1 [
            0 => "*"
          ]
        }
        2 => WebsiteMenuItem {#646
          #keyType: "string"
          #fillable: array:7 [
            0 => "id"
            1 => "title"
            2 => "label"
            3 => "imagem"
            4 => "website_image"
            5 => "icons"
            6 => "submenu"
          ]
          #connection: null
          #table: null
          #primaryKey: "id"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: false
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #attributes: array:2 [
            "title" => "Como Funciona o Consórcio"
            "id" => "header_submenu_menu.2.2"
          ]
          #original: []
          #changes: []
          #casts: []
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #appends: []
          #dispatchesEvents: []
          #observables: []
          #relations: []
          #touches: []
          +timestamps: true
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #guarded: array:1 [
            0 => "*"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

var_dump($array_youd_like_to_print) will give you all the contents (even nested) of an array.

You can either use this as is, if it solves your problem, or use it to find where the value is that you are looking for (and how to access it in the array) and print that.

Comment: the dd ($ menu) returns me all the data up to the submenus, but I wanted to grab each menu index and check if it has submenu in it, if it has, just list the title of it.

Comment: You can use a foreach loop. eg:
foreach ($menuItems as $menuItem) {
// Do something with $menuItem here (maybe check if it has the value you want?)
}

Comment: Hm, I'll try it here

Comment: But yaml's data is not an object, it's just an array.

Comment: You can use yaml_parse() or other yaml php function to parse the data from yaml to php object.